# Why am I getting undefined instead of a function using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I'm using React Router v4.0.0-alpha.3 with create-react-app like so:

```
// For react app
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss } from 'react-router';

import './css/style.css';
// For electron app ~
import './ReactotronConfig'
import StorePicker from './components/StorePicker'
import App from './components/App'

class NotFound extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Not Found.</div>
    )
  }
}

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Match exactly pattern="/" component={StorePicker} />
        <Match pattern="/store/:storeId" component={App} />
        <Miss component={NotFound} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}


render(
  <Root />,
  document.querySelector('#main')
)
```

I'm getting these errors.

[image: Render Method Errors]

The only thing I've found to cause this online is that I could be importing incorrectly, but AFAIK I am. I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something glaringly obvious.

Code for App and Storepicker:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import Order from './Order'
import Inventory from './Inventory'

const App = ({...props}) => (
  <div className='catch-of-the-day'>
    <div className='menu'>
      <Header tagline="Fresh Seafood Market" />
    </div>
    <Order />
    <Inventory />
  </div>
)

export default App
```

--

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class StorePicker extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form className='store-selector'>
        <h2>Please Enter A Store</h2>
        <input type='text' required placeholder='Store Name'/>
        <button type='submit'>Visit Store ☞</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default StorePicker
```

Comment: Did you correctly `export` your `StorePicker` and `App` components?

Comment: @Timo Yes, both are `export default` at bottom of file.

Comment: Could you share the relevant code of the two components? I.e. class definition and export?

Comment: I don't know much of React so correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the problem that the `Root` element isn't neither a class and neither inherits from `React.Component` so it doesn't has a `render()` method?

Comment: @Timo Sure; edited

Comment: @GGG React _should_ render a function as long as it implicitly returns a ReactElement i.e. `return ( { /* your el */ } )`.

Comment: @WillJ.Haggard Even if it says it *should* I'd give it a try, but it might just be my inexperience in react.